# Combine subjects in RxJS similar to zip

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to combine two subjects in similar way as zip does, but with the following important difference.

I want an observables that combines two subjects in this way. When both have emitted values, emit the latest of their values. Then, both need to emit at least once again, then emit their latest emitted values. Etc.

Both subjects:

1 ---------- 2 ----- 3 -- 4 ------------------- 5 ——

------- a ------------------- b --- c — d —-————

Goal observable:

------- 1a ----------------- 4b ---————-5d —-

Simple example: subject1 emits 5 times and after that subject2 emits once. The first emitted value of zip is a pair of both first emits of the subjects. I want (subj1-emit5, subj2-emit1).

Answer (score 4):

I think you could achieve what you want easily by just using `combineLatest()` with `take(1)`. Then to repeat the process add `repeat()` operator that will resubscribe after each sequence:

```
import { Subject, combineLatest, take, repeat } from 'rxjs';

const s1$ = new Subject<number>();
const s2$ = new Subject<string>();

combineLatest([s1$, s2$]).pipe(
  take(1),
  repeat(),
).subscribe(console.log);

setTimeout(() => s1$.next(1), 0);
setTimeout(() => s2$.next('a'), 200);
setTimeout(() => s1$.next(2), 300);
setTimeout(() => s1$.next(3), 400);
setTimeout(() => s1$.next(4), 500);
setTimeout(() => s2$.next('b'), 600);
setTimeout(() => s2$.next('c'), 700);
setTimeout(() => s2$.next('d'), 800);
setTimeout(() => s1$.next(5), 900);

// Prints: [1, 'a'], [4, 'b'], [5, 'd']
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4vg6lu?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: Super elegant solution, “per intenditori” as we say

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed building an `almostZip` function with something like this (comments within the code to explain the logic)

```
function almostZip(o1$: Observable<any>, o2$: Observable<any>) {
  // we create a variable within the closure to hold the state of the Observable
  // in particular we store the values emitted by the 2 Observables received as input
  const valuesEmitted = [null, null]
  const _o1$ = o1$.pipe(
    // when o1$ emits, then we load the value emitted into the state variable first position
    tap(v => valuesEmitted[0] = v)
  )
  const _o2$ = o2$.pipe(
    // when o2$ emits, then we load the value emitted into the state variable second position
    tap(v => valuesEmitted[1] = v)
  )

  // this is the Observable returned by the function almostZip
  return merge(_o1$, _o2$).pipe(
    // filter out all notifications until both slots of the state var are not null
    // if both are not null, then it means that we are in the position
    // to notify the pair - this is hopefully going to be clear
    // few lines below when we reset the state after notification
    filter(() => {
      return !!valuesEmitted[0] && !!valuesEmitted[1]
    }),
    // notify a copy of the state
    // we must emit a coy of the state, and not the state, since we
    // are going to reset the state soon, in the next lines
    map(() => [...valuesEmitted]),
    // reset the state
    // once we have notified a pair of values, one from the first
    // Observable one from the second, we have to reset the state
    // to accumulate the next pair
    tap(() => {
      valuesEmitted[0] = null
      valuesEmitted[1] = null
    }),
  )
}
```

Here a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ytplfe?file=index.ts) that represents how this work

Answer (score -1):

How about [`withLatestFrom`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) ?

```
import './style.css';

import { rx, of, tap, interval, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs';
const obs1$ = interval(1000);
const obs2$ = interval(5000);

obs2$
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(obs1$),
    tap(([first, second]) => {
      console.log(`second Source (5s): ${first} first Source (1s): ${second}`);
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

// Open the console in the bottom right to see results.
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xe1qtv)